# How to find the process that is causing deadlock in MSSQL

Tags: linux

I am getting latency arrival and departure from an on board computer to a third party application that generates XML file with the information gathered from the OBC.

I tried to update the statuses of some of the transaction in the DB to all the 3rd party application to process the information, but it hasn't helped.

Below is the high level of chronological order of logic in MIF scheduler code for Arrival and Depart OBC interfaces ( `MPNL.Services:mapPacosEvent`):

- Perform:

  ```
  Select uniqkey, status, vehicle_number, created_datetime, msn, base_msn, message_type, form_id, message_text from ALLINBOUNDMESSAGES where 
  status IN (0,6,7,8,9) AND (form_id = '003' OR form_id = '005') AND ((message_type = 'pacos') OR (message_type = 'form'))
  ORDER BY created_datetime
  ```
- For each row result of the above query from the message_text get the dispatch_number. E.g.

  ```
  Vehicle 103184 has arrived at Stop #5 (310466-000) at 2019-07-19 08:00:14 (local time).^886727^5^310466-000^41.412191^-73.454032^68139.250^401773.3
  ```

  here the dispatch_id is 886727)
- Perform:

  ```
  select dispatch_id, driver from dispatch where dispatch_number='${dispatch_number}' ORDER BY created_datetime DESC
  ```
- Perform:

  ```
  select status,dispatch_number,stop_number,scheduled_arrival,stopprofile_id,planned5, planned4 ,planned3 ,planned2 from dispstops where dispatch_id='${dispatch_id}' AND stop_number='${stop_number}' AND status IN (${StopStatusValue}) ORDER BY Status Asc ,stop_number DESC.
  ```

  Here the Stop_number and StopStatusVaues are read from the `MPNLInboundInterfaces_ConfigFile.xml` file.
- Perform:

  ```
  select DISTINCT t1.login ,t1.login_datime_gmt from vehicleloginxref t1
  join [elogevents] t2 ON ((t1.vehicle_number = t2.vehicle_number) AND (t1.login = t2.driverid))
  where((t1.status = '${status}') AND (t1.userstatus = '${userstatus}') AND (t2.eid = '${eid}') AND (t1.vehicle_number='${vehicle_number}') AND (t1.logout_datime_gmt IS NULL)) ORDER BY login_datime_gmt DESC
  ```

  Here the input is `status`, `eid` and `vehicle_number`.
- Perform:

  ```
  select primary driver detail from TPNE using below query
    select secondary_driver, carrier_driver_id   from driver where secondary_driver != '' and secondary_driver is not null AND mark_for_deletion!='1'
  ```
- Perform:

  ```
  Select TP_company_ID,LAST_KNOWN_FACILITY_ALIAS_ID,CARRIER_ID from DRIVER where Carrier_Driver_ID ='${DriverID}' AND mark_for_deletion!='1'
  ```
- Perform:

  ```
  Select Last known FacilityAliasID from TPE
                             Select TP_company_ID,LAST_KNOWN_FACILITY_ALIAS_ID,CARRIER_ID from DRIVER where Carrier_Driver_ID ='${DriverID}' AND mark_for_deletion!='1'
                             select carrier_code from carrier_code where TP_company_ID= '${TPCompanyID}' and CARRIER_ID='${CARRIER_ID}'
                             select gmtoffset from opcenters where opcenter = (select opCenter from vehicles where vehicle_number = ’${vehicle_number}' )
                             select time_zone_name from time_zone where time_zone_id = (select min(time_zone_id)  from time_zone where gmt_offset = '${gmtoffset}')
                             select uniqkey,vehicle_number,created_datetime,msn,base_msn,form_id,dispatchstop,on_dock_time,trailer,pro,seal,detention_hours,auto_latlong,
  auto_location,auto_odometer,userflag1,userflag2,userfield1,userfield2,dispatch_number,stop_number from ${tablename1} where msn='${msn}' AND 
  base_msn='${base_msn}' AND vehicle_number='${vehicle_number}' AND userflag1 NOT in ('${successStatus}','${errorStatus}')
  ```
- Scheduler service `MPNL.Services:mapPacosEvent` composes `Arrival_OBC` and `Depart_OBC` xmls using the information pulled from `TPNE` and `PeopleNet` database and sends the same to MIF.
- Once the message sent to `MIF` successfully scheduler updates the `ALLINBOUNDMESSAGES` table using the below query:

  ```
  Update status=’1’ where uniqkey=’’ and vehicle_number=’’ and message_type=’’ and form_id=’’;
  ```
- If sending the `Arrival_OBC` and `Depart_OBC` xmls fails scheduler updates the ALLINBOUNDMESSAGES table using the below query:

  ```
  Update status=’10’ where uniqkey=’’ and vehicle_number=’’ and message_type=’’ and form_id=’’
  ```

The error:

```
2019-07-17 14:02:00 EDT [ART.0114.1007E] Adapter Runtime: Error Logged. See Error log for details. Error: [ADA.1.316] Cannot execute the SQL statement "UPDATE  allinboundmessages SET status = ?  WHERE uniqkey = ? AND vehicle_number = ? AND message_type = ? AND form_id = ?". "
(40001/1205) Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."
Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
2019-07-17 14:02:00 EDT [ART.0114.1007E] Adapter Runtime: Error Logged. See Error log for details. Error: [ART.117.4002] Adapter Runtime (Adapter Service): Unable to invoke adapter service MPNL.AdapterServices:updateAllInboundMessageRecs.
[ADA.1.316] Cannot execute the SQL statement "UPDATE  allinboundmessages SET status = ?  WHERE uniqkey = ? AND vehicle_number = ? AND message_type = ? AND form_id = ?". "
(40001/1205) Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."
Transaction (Process ID 78) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run the stored proc sp_who2, it will show you what processes are blocked and what process is doing the blocking.

Comment: Please feel free to let me know why you down voted this answer.